# ReactiveCocoa. Return type 'UIImage *' must match previous return type 'void *'

Tags: objective-c, ios7, reactive-cocoa

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic) PhotoEffect *effect;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *glossSwitch;
```

I'm trying to update `imageView` with a modified image, when `UISwitch` changed its value, or `_image` and `_effect` were changed.

```
RAC(self.imageView, image) = [RACSignal
                                  combineLatest:@[ RACObserve(self, image), RACObserve(self.glossSwitch, on), RACObserve(self, effect)]
                                  reduce:^(UIImage *im, NSNumber *gloss, PhotoEffect *effect) {
                                      if (!im) {
                                          return nil;
                                      }
                                      if (effect) {
                                          im = [im imageWithEffect:effect.type];
                                      }
                                      if (gloss.boolValue) {
                                          im = [GlossyIcon applyShineToImage:im];
                                      }
                                      return im;
                                  }];
```

This code gives a compiler error, which I can't understand:

```
Return type 'UIImage *' must match previous return type 'void *' 
when block literal has unspecified explicit return type
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your reduce block can return `nil` or `UIImage *`, the compiler can't infer the return type of the block. Explicitly declaring a return type for the reduce block will fix the problem, you can use `id` for brevity, or `UIImage *` to be clear.

```
    reduce:^UIImage * (UIImage *im, …) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the reason. Probably you can answer another question :) Why ```RACObserve(self.glossSwitch, on)``` doesn't react on change?

Comment: Solved. RC doesn't like when ivars assigned through *_* instead of *self.*